# `inferior-haskell-type` inside a `where` clause?

Tags: haskell, emacs

Does haskell-mode or some alternative package offer something akin to the wonderful `inferior-haskell-type` *inside* a `where` clause?

For example, suppose I have

```
foo = undefined where
    bar = complicated
    ...
```

it would be super-awesome to be able to place the marker at `bar` and inspect its type.

Comment: I suppose for something like this to work, Emacs would have to take everything from the where clause and make a temporary module (importing the original module), and then load it.

Comment: IIRC this was possible with earlier Scion versions in combination with Emacs. (Quote from the documentation: `C-c C-t` shows type of identifier at point. This only works if the current file typechecks, but then it also works for local identifiers.)

Comment: @hvr : Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: jfyi, I just tried it with my [fork for GHC 7.0](https://github.com/hvr/scion) and it still works more or less

Comment: @hvr: you should add this as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with [Scion](https://github.com/nominolo/scion) in combination with Emacs.

> `C-c C-t` shows type of identifier at point. This only works if the current file typechecks, but then it also works for local identifiers. For polymorphic function it will show the type to which they are instantiated, e.g.,
>
> ```
> f x = x + (1::Int)
> ```
>
> Calling this command on `+` will print `Int -> Int -> Int` instead of `Num a => a -> a -> a`.